# how to label the x and y axis - in a line graph

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using js and `chart.js`, I'm trying to label my x & y axis and no matter which example I try nothing works, in my code a few examples
1. change using `labels`, 2, change using `label` inside the `axes`
 .. How to name my x and y ?

```
var vtx = document.getElementById("nowChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(vtx, {
    type: 'line',
    labels: [{ xLabels: "Days" }, {yLabels:"Ways"} ],
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'IBM graph',
            data: mydata,
            showLine: true,
            pointBackgroundColor: "#00ff11",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,

        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                label:"Days"

            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                label: "Rays"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked for me, enjoy

options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'probability'
      }
    }]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks wrong. Take a look at the chart.js [line graph sample](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/line/line.html) to see how to correctly do this.